# Object is wrong type

Tags: c++, types, sfml

Basically for some reason new object is wrong type. All source code is on github https://github.com/teuro/sfml-radar. If it's help please fork at will.

I have following class:

```
#ifndef _VIEW_HPP
#define _VIEW_HPP

#include <iostream>

#include "sfml_drawsurface.hpp"

class View {
protected:
    View(Drawsurface& d) : drawer(d) {
        std::clog << "View::View()" << std::endl;
    }

    Drawsurface& drawer;

    virtual void draw() = 0;
};


#endif
```

That is base class for all different kind of views. Now I have derived sub-class

```
#ifndef _GAME_VIEW_HPP
#define _GAME_VIEW_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include "view.hpp"
#include "../models/game.hpp"

class Gameview : public View {
public:
    Gameview(Drawsurface& d);
    ~Gameview();
    void draw();
private:
    Drawsurface& drawer;
};

#endif // _GAME_VIEW_HPP
```

Then abstract class Drawsurface

```
/**
    * drawsurface base for all graphics pure abstract
    * provide only interface quite high-level
    * 2014/06/02
    * Juha Teurokoski
**/

#ifndef _DRAWSURFACE_HPP
#define _DRAWSURFACE_HPP

#include <string>

#include "../models/point.hpp"

class Drawsurface {
public:
    bool font_loaded;
    virtual void rectangleColor(Point& a, Point& b, unsigned int color) = 0;
    virtual void lineColor(Point& a, Point& b, unsigned int color) = 0;
    virtual void circleColor(Point& a, unsigned int rad, unsigned int color) = 0;
    virtual void trigonColor(Point& a, Point& b, Point& c, unsigned int color) = 0;
    virtual void trigonColor(Point& a, unsigned int size, unsigned int color) = 0;
    virtual void load_font(std::string font) = 0;

    virtual void draw_picture(std::string tiedosto, Point& a, bool center = false) = 0;
    virtual void draw_text(std::string text, Point& a, unsigned int color = 0) = 0;

    virtual int get_fontsize() = 0;
    virtual void flip() = 0;
    virtual void clear_screen() = 0;

    virtual ~Drawsurface() { }
};

#endif
```

Now if I create new instance of sfml_drawsurface which is sub-class of Drawsurface. For some reason new object is Drawsuface istead of sfml_drawsurface. Below is sfml_drawsurface class.

```
#ifndef SFML_DRAWSURFACE_HPP
#define SFML_DRAWSURFACE_HPP
/**
    * sfml-drawsurface provides basic drawing, pictures and text
    * require drawsurface
    * 2014/06/02
    * Juha Teurokoski
**/

#include "drawsurface.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class sfml_drawsurface : public Drawsurface {
public:
    sfml_drawsurface(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    ~sfml_drawsurface();

    void rectangleColor(Point& a, Point& b, unsigned int color);
    void circleColor(Point& a, unsigned int rad, unsigned int color);
    void lineColor(Point& a, Point& b, unsigned int color);
    void trigonColor(Point& a, Point& b, Point& c, unsigned int color);
    void trigonColor(Point& a, unsigned int _size, unsigned int color);

    void draw_picture(std::string tiedosto, Point& a, bool center = false);
    void draw_text(std::string text, Point& a, unsigned int color);
    void load_font(std::string font);
    void clear_screen();

    int get_fontsize();
    void flip();
protected:
private:
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
    sf::Font font;

    sf::Color active;
    sf::Color normal;
};

#endif // SFML_DRAWSURFACE_HPP
```

I create new object like this:

```
sfml_drawsurface drawer(window);

this->gameview = new Gameview(drawer);
std::clog << typeid(drawer).name() << std::endl;
```

And everything seems to be right, because std::clog outout is '16sfml_drawsurface'.

Next place is draw-method then happens something really weird.

Same print is now '11Drawsurface'.

Comment: Your include guards are all [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: The only immediate oddity I see in this code is that none of your *derived* class destructors are declared virtual. Why you do this I cannot say (and its too early and not enough caffeine for me to remember whether it even matters or not).

Comment: Most likely, `drawer` goes out of scope before you call `draw`, leaving `gameview` with a dangling reference to the destroyed object. You need to make sure it lasts as long as anything that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Mike had the right idea. From your Program.cpp file you have in your constructor:

```
Program::Program() {
    Game game;
    ...
    this->gamecontroller = new Gamecontroller(game);  //Probably also bad

    sfml_drawsurface drawer(window);
    this->gameview = new Gameview(drawer);  
}
```

The problem is that `drawer` ceases to exist once the constructor is finished leaving you with a dangling reference and undefined behaviour. Looks like you may have the same problem with the `game` variable.

Solution is to not have them as local variables but as either class members (preferred) or dynamically allocated (it depends how long you need to have them around).

Comment: Yep solution was to move gamecontroller, game and gameview out of constructor. Now I pass them while I create new program object.